# "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'" error in simple console application

Tags: c#, .net-core

I get this error in the C# password control:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Would you please help?

```
int newPassPP2 = 19;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the Password : ");

int readNewPassword = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int writeNewPassword(int newNumOne)
{
    return newNumOne == readNewPassword ? "Number is true" : "Number is false";
}
Console.WriteLine(writeNewPassword(newPassPP2));
```

The error happens on this line of code:

```
return newNumOne == readNewPassword ? "Number is true" : "Number is false";
```

Thanks

Comment: Your local function (`writeNewPassword`) needs to return `string` and not `int`

Comment: why not writeNewPassword return to integer? @pinkfloydx33

Comment: Because "Number is true" and "Number is false" are `string`s and that's what you're returning from the local function

Comment: not sure why people downvote this question.  It is pretty strait forward, and seems to meet the guidelines.  Seems to me people are just downvoting due to the your lack of understanding what is happening (which is why you are asking amirite?).

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a string from the local method

```
   ...

   string writeNewPassword(int newNumOne)
   {
      return newNumOne == readNewPassword ? "Number is true" : "Number is false";
   }
   Console.WriteLine(writeNewPassword(newPassPP2));

   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method return type is **`int`** right now change it to datatype of **`string`**,

```
private string myMethod()
```